# How to detect socket disconnection on client side?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using `nodejs v0.11.0-pre` and `socket.io version 0.9.11` and I want to detect socket disconnection on client side. I am using this code to do alert on disconnect this but it seems that I am doing some thing wrong any one can help, thanks

Client:

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1',{port:4000});
  console.log("connected");  
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        alert('disconnected');
    });
</script>
```

Server:

```
var http = require('http');
var app = http.createServer().listen(4000)
,io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("client has established :" + socket.id);
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log("client has disconnected :" + socket.id);
});       
});
```

Every thing works fine on the server, but there is no alert on disconnect on client.

Answer (score 4):

Do as follows:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1:8080');

    socket.on('connect', function() { console.log("connected"); });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () { console.log("disconnected"); });
</script>
```

and your listener port must be same as the connect uses that.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no such thing as connection on server side and/or browser
>   side. There is only one connection. If one of the sides closes it,
>   then it is closed (and you cannot push data to a connection that is
>   closed obviously). **Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/18147207/973155

You can however close the connection yourself from the client side:

```
socket.disconnect();
```