# Closing a net socket does not cause event on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, events

I am trying to close a socket and handle the event accordingly on the server. I tried using client.destroy() and client.end() and catching the events 'end', 'close', 'error' and 'timeout' and none of the callbacks are firing.

I use this to kill the socket:

```
setTimeout(() => { 
   console.log("destroy"); 
   e._destroyed = true; 
   e._client.end(); 
   e._client.destroy(); 
   logger.debug("Test"); 
}, 1000);
```

and this is the constructor of my connection class:

```
constructor(socket, id, onData, onEnd)
{
    this._onDataHandler = onData;
    this._onEndHandler = onEnd;
    this._socket = socket;
    this._socket.setEncoding('UTF-8');
    this._socket.on('data', this._onData.bind(this));
    this._socket.on('end', this._onEnd.bind(this));
    this._socket.on('close', this._onEnd.bind(this));
    this._socket.on('error', this._onEnd.bind(this));
    this._socket.on('timeout', this._onEnd.bind(this));
    this._id = id;
}
```

This is the onEnd method:

```
_onEnd()
{
    if(this.onEndHandler)
        this._onEndHandler(this);
}
```

which in turn should call this:

```
_onEnd(connection) {
    console.log("Killing connection " + connection);
    let index = this._connections.id;
    this._removeConnection(this._subscriptions, index);
    this._connections[index] = null;
}
```

This is the output I am getting:

> destroy
>   [26.05.2017 - 14:05:56] [Timeout.static.main.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (Core.Main:20:118)] [DEBUG] Test

and nothing further. So the killing connection is never called, besides being bound to all possible "connection-ending" events. Is this expected ? Am I missing a method or some config here ? Or must the error be somewhere else ?

PS: The socket is closed on the client, trying to write to it will give the according error.

Comment: This could help (`socket.disconnect()`) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126677/node-js-socket-io-close-client-connection

Comment: This gives me `TypeError: e._client.disconnect is not a function`. The socket is created via net.connect(), so it definitely is a socket object. It is also not listed in the official docs: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html

Comment: Oh, I thought you were using Socket.io. Any reason why you're not using it? Cause it's super simple.

Comment: I want to use as few dependencies as possible, and since node already has a net library onboard, I see no reason as not to use it. Still, I think it shouldn't be that hard to orderly close a connection.

Comment: Where is your onEndHandler? Seems like you have two _onEnd methods?

Comment: oh god, I missed the _ in if(this.onEndHandler). Sorry guys, was just my stupidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a typo in my code:

```
_onEnd()
{
    if(this.onEndHandler)
        this._onEndHandler(this);
}
```

is missing the underscore in the if clause. Now it works as expected.